# Lua / Love2d: Erro quando tento dar require.tree("code") : Attempt to index global 'require' (a function value)

Tags: lua, lua-table, love2d

Erro quando tento dar require.tree("code") : Attempt to index global 'require' (a function value)

```
function love.load()
    lib = require.tree("code")
end
```

sendo code uma pasta com arquivos .lua dentro

Answer (score 1):

Olá, boa noite! Pelo que eu entendi, você está tentando importar no codigo uma library, correto? Geralmete faço isso da seguinte forma:

```
function love.load()
    lib = require "nome da pasta ou arquivo"
end
```

um exemplo com uma library de física que eu uso muito:

```
function love.load()
    HC = require "libs/HC"
end
```

Então possivelmente pode ser o ".tree" após o "require". Tente verificar isso, e me passe qualquer duvida ou resultado.

Espero ter ajudado.

**Bons Códigos :)**

**ASS.:** ***MarcosDev***